# Return Void Pointer and Convert Hex to UINT

Tags: c, pointers, void

I have been trying to figure this out, but any help shall be appreciated.
I have this function -

```
 void * func1(void * a)
 {
  return (void *)0x123;
 }
```

Now, when I retrieve the Value, I get some random numbers in 1E4 etc etc. Here is my code to retrieve -

```
void * check = func1;
printf(1,"%x\n", (uint)check);
```

I do understand Void pointers but this is something getting above my head. I want to print "0x123"

Comment: Edited. Mistyped previously. Thank You for letting me know.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to *call* the function:

```
void *check = func1(0);
```

Turn up your compiler warnings!

Comment: Thank You. This worked. but, why should I need to call it. I am so sorry, I assumed it to be function pointer. Thank You so much.

Comment: Your previous code did print out a function pointer. You said that's not what you wanted.

Comment: Yes. There are two different values coming. One with function pointer and other which is returned. I got confused with the return value. Thanks for helping.